# How to create schema Array in data frame with spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have code to create data frame and this works fine if there is no array in my input data.

I tried using Json data which doen't have array and it runs successfully.
My code is

```
val vals = sc.parallelize(
  """{"id":"1","name":"alex"}""" ::
  Nil
)

val schema = (new StructType)
      .add("id", StringType)
      .add("name", StringType)


  sqlContext.read.schema(schema).json(vals).select($"*").printSchema()
```

My question is, if I have input data with array like below then how to create schema?

```
     val vals = sc.parallelize(
  """{"id":"1","name":"alex","score":[{"keyword":"read","point":10}]}""" ::
  Nil
)


val schema = (new StructType)
      .add("id", StringType)
      .add("name", StringType)
```

Thanks.

Comment: there are so many articles on it on the web. what have you tried?

Answer (score 7):

Oke, I could have solution in my code.

Create schema in array in data frame spark you can this code.

```
val vals = sc.parallelize(
  """{"id":"1","name":"alex","score":[{"keyword":"read","point":10}]}""" ::
  Nil
)

val schema = StructType(
      Array(
        StructField("id", StringType),
        StructField("name", StringType),
        StructField("score", ArrayType(StructType(Array(
          StructField("keyword", StringType),
          StructField("point", IntegerType)
        ))))
      )
    )
```

and you print schema

```
sqlContext.read.schema(schema).json(vals).select($"*").printSchema()
```

Thanks is resolved